# using like operator in if operator in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a textbox for search (that is, textBox1)
A user, for example, enters "aba" in textBox1.
"abandon" puts in datagridiew1.
The user clicks on datagriview1:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox_MWE.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    if ("richTextBox_MWE.Text like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'")
    {
        label5.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

I want if "abandon" is such as "aba" in textBox1, label5.BackColor becomes Green.

Comment: Generally, you'd like to consider Regular Expressions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) as a .NET equivalent for SQL LIKE operator, but in this particular case you can just use .Contains() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way is use the textBox1(where actually filter content going to change) change event

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox_MWE.Text) && richTextBox_MWE.Text.Trim().Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
{
  label5.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I also want customed Contains Function, that is, If I enter "1" just Contains Function findes "1" not "11" or "21" or ....

Answer (score 2):

You want to use some kind of mix of `C#` and `sql` :) You can use the [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to achieve what you want.

```
if(richTextBox_MWE.Text != null
    && richTextBox_MWE.Text.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox_MWE.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox_MWE.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && richTextBox_MWE.Text.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
    {
        label5.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Here the contains will accept the value to be searched.

Comment: '' like '%%' is true.

Answer (score 0):

See snippet from my code. The txtProductCode is a text box that user is filling the product_code for searching in the list view.

```
        string tmpProductCode = txtProductCode.Text.Trim();
        string tmpProductCodePattern = "^" + Regex.Escape(tmpProductCode).Replace("%", ".*") + "$";
```

In my loop of product_code(s) the prodCode will contain the product_code value for each loop.

```
        productCodeClause = false;              
        if (tmpProductCode.Equals(""))
        {
            productCodeClause = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(prodCode, tmpProductCodePattern))
            {
                productCodeClause = true;
            }
        }
```

I hope this will be helpful.